# Replacing keys in dictionary conditional on its value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to remove the last character of keys in dictionary if its value is 1:

```
d = {'hours': 1, 'seconds': 30}

for k,v in d.items():
      if v == 1:
        print(k)
        d[k[:-1]] = d.pop(k)
```

However, it keeps popping until the key is left with 1 character. hours in this case becomes h when it should become hour.

Comment: I hope you are only dealing with times  ;) . This logic will break for words that follow 
a different plural pattern`{'sheep': 1}` will become `shee`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d = {'hours': 1, 'seconds': 30}

for k,v in list(d.items()):
  if v == 1:
    print(k)
    d[k[:-1]] = d.pop(k)
```

This should solve the issue, the reason for your code is not working since you're modifying the dict in the loop and iterator is getting changed. It has unpredictable behavior.